# Can we change the returned oembed YouTube iframe width and height?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Now the YouTube return min. width and height. How can adjust the GET call to change the return `html`?
e.g:

```
"html": "<iframe width=\"400\" height=\"260\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/kFz9afj8lu0?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
```

Current
https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFz9afj8lu0

```
{
"title": "Can You Actually Game in 8K? (RTX 3090 Gameplay!)",
"author_name": "Marques Brownlee",
"author_url": "https://www.youtube.com/c/mkbhd",
"type": "video",
"height": 113,
"width": 200,
"version": "1.0",
"provider_name": "YouTube",
"provider_url": "https://www.youtube.com/",
"thumbnail_height": 360,
"thumbnail_width": 480,
"thumbnail_url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kFz9afj8lu0/hqdefault.jpg",
"html": "<iframe width=\"200\" height=\"113\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/kFz9afj8lu0?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there is an oEmbed spec: https://oembed.com

If you look down in section

> 2.2. Consumer Request

You will note there are `maxwidth` and `maxheight` options.

Add `&maxwidth=400&maxheight=260` to your GET request, like so:

https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFz9afj8lu0&maxwidth=400&maxheight=260

This will return the following:

```
{
  "title": "Can You Actually Game in 8K? (RTX 3090 Gameplay!)",
  "author_name": "Marques Brownlee",
  "author_url": "https://www.youtube.com/c/mkbhd",
  "type": "video",
  "height": 225,
  "width": 400,
  "version": "1.0",
  "provider_name": "YouTube",
  "provider_url": "https://www.youtube.com/",
  "thumbnail_height": 360,
  "thumbnail_width": 480,
  "thumbnail_url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kFz9afj8lu0/hqdefault.jpg",
  "html": "\u003ciframe width=\u0022400\u0022 height=\u0022225\u0022 src=\u0022https://www.youtube.com/embed/kFz9afj8lu0?feature=oembed\u0022 frameborder=\u00220\u0022 allow=\u0022accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\u0022 allowfullscreen\u003e\u003c/iframe\u003e"
}
```

The `html` property, after `decodeURIComponent`, now looks like your example:

```
<iframe width=\"400\" height=\"225\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/kFz9afj8lu0?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```